# VueJs doesn't show component`s source code

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I started working with the vueJS2 relatively recently, now I'm studying the components and I had a question for the experts.

As far as I know, the VueJS processes the HTML using JavaScript, and it is because of this that the rest of the HTML code is not visible.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

view in Chrome browser

[image]

view in IDE

[image]

view in Chrome Source Code

[image]

You can see there is no `<button>` tag in Chrome source code

How can I make it so that when I use the components, I want to display the HTML completely FULL, as an example here:

source code of my jQuery DataTable

[image]

Another question related to the topic. Does it matter that the components reduce the whole HTML to 'one line ' for a search in the browsers?

Comment: Sounds like you could use some awesome devtools: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en & some vue-awesome: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue (just for fun)

Comment: any relevant code you want to include into your post should be copy and pasted (and formatted) instead of a screen shot. It will allow people to help you better.

Comment: @AndrewLohr Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see the HTML within the source code because the compilation takes place after the source code has already been generated.

What you can do however is right clicking your component and selecting `Inspect` within Chrome. This works because the `elements` tab shows a live representation of your code, so therefore it also shows the compiled component markup.

If you want further debugging tools you can check out the Vue devtools Chrome extension.

This does not work like jQuery for the reason that Vue takes a `data-driven` approach. Your data is in charge of what you markup is going to look like. jQuery usually enhances the HTML that is already there.

Comment: Thank you for your very informative reply!
But is it still possible to use the components of Vue that the HTML code was loaded and the browser search saw it?

Comment: Google is able to crawl JavaScript rendered pages. Google will still prefer SSR pages over JavaScript rendered pages because it is not perfect yet at indexing JavaScript rendered pages. If you want to be 100% sure your SEO will work, you need to implement server side rendering https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html this way it will show up in your source code.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i was looking for!